# Need help to read Fraktur from a 18th century book

Tags: german-to-english, history, mathematics, blackletter

I am reading Euler's German translation of his work on differential calculus entitled Vollständige Anleitung zur Differentialrechnung (Complete instruction on Differential Calculus). I am struggling to go through the Fraktur and the archaic words of 18th century German.

[image]

My knowledge of German language is very limited so I wish to ask whether I get the underlined words correctly. In the order from left to right:

1. benden
2. letsten
3. indess
4. setzen
5. Aendert

Did I write it correctly?
The whole sentence is:

> Diese benden letsten Dinge wollen wir indess den Seite setzen, um den Fall nicht zu sehr zu verwickeln. Aendert...

Is this sentence correct? What is its meaning?

Comment: Related [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/55263/1696) concerning typical replacement patterns.

Comment: Euler's book was translated in 1790 from Latin to German. See https://books.google.de/books?id=EOdXAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP5 . The text occurs on  page 48.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The sentence is:

> Diese beyden letzten Dinge wollen wir indeß bey Seite setzen, um den Fall nicht zu sehr zu verwickeln. Aendert...

Some of the words had a different spelling in that time.
What you considered an "n" is a "y", there are several words that were spelled with "ey" where nowadays it is "ei". This is the case in your word 1) *beyden* - modern spelling *beiden* = both and in the word *bey* (modern spelling *bei*) that you didn't mark.
Perhaps you just made a typo in 2) when you wrote *letsten*, because you correctly identified the same letters as "tz" in 4) *setzen*
3) is *indeß*, the modern spelling is *indes*
You are right with 5) - "Ae" is an alternative for "Ä" in case you can't use Umlaute.

Instead of *bey Seite* the modern spelling would be *beiseite*.

A translation of that sentence would be

> However, we want to put aside these last two things (depending on context, objects or items might be a better English equivalent) in order to not make the case too complicated. If one changes...

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This book is definitely old.

Comment: @JamesWarthington As the answer illustrates, no archaic words are involved, just dated spelling.

Comment: Modern spelling would be *Diese beiden letzten Dinge wollen wir indes beiseitesetzen, um den Fall nicht zu sehr zu verwickeln. Ändert...* You could argue that *beiseitesetzen* is archaic wording. Today people would more likely say *beiseitelegen*.

Comment: Following more modern concepts I would probably turn the whole sentence around in modern German, "Um den Fall nicht unnötig aufzublähen, wollen wir die letzten beiden Fakten auslassen / hier nicht betrachten"  or some similar wording

Comment: I just read that Ae actually predates Ä: It was Ae with a superscripted e, then the e got abbreviated to just two dots, then the dots moves over the A. (No reliable source for that, unfortunately.) My speculation is that typesetting then had a tendency to move back to Ae because that's one letter less you have to keep in your typecase.

Comment: @Volker Landgraf: So bei Seite setzen means put sth aside?

Comment: @JamesWarthington Almost. *bey Seite setzen* (modern spelling would be *beiseitesetzen* - or rather *beiseitelegen*, as Christian Geiselmann pointed out) means *to put aside*. *Something* (often abbrevated sth) would be *etwas*.